# Admin Grid "Select All" for mass action only sends the visible IDs

Tags: magento2, grid, massaction, multiselect

I'm having some trouble getting "Select All" working properly for a custom grid.

I have a massDelete action working and deleting multiple items. I have a multiselect column which, after I run a "Select All", displays the fact that the full count is selected (It says that the full count of 150 oo so items are selected). The problem is that when I run the massDelete action after a "Select All", only the 20 or so items on the current page are deleted.

Here is my Mass Action:

```xml
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">rule_listing.rule_listing.rule_listing_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

Here is the selectionsColumn

```xml
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</selectionsColumn>
```

My controller is using the following code:

```php
$this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create())
foreach ($collection as $model) {
    $model->delete();
}
```

I have checked the values that are being POSTed to the controller. There is no difference between what is POSTed after doing a "Select All" compared to selecting the first page.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is an upstream bug:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23110

Solution:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22704/commits/595a7a8f56571a5bd2753096bef9db27d46020ff

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Did so - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an upstream bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23110

Solution:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22704/commits/595a7a8f56571a5bd2753096bef9db27d46020ff

app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/massactions.js - remove the following lines (156-160):

```
if (itemsType === 'excluded' && data.selected && data.selected.length) {
  itemsType = 'selected';
  data[itemsType] = _.difference(data.selected, data.excluded);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Magento 2.3.3 where you can now do a mass action on more than 200 items.

So long as you have selectedProvider configured correctly there should be no problems getting ids in the controller now.

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days I found the solution.

```
public function execute()
{
    $collectionSize = 0;
    $parameterData = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
   //For selected Ids only
    if(array_key_exists("selected", $parameterData))  
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }    
    }else if(!array_key_exists("selected", $parameterData) && array_key_exists("excluded", $parameterData))   //For select all
    {
      
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }    
    }
    

    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

I hope someone will find this helpful.