How to get "Select All" orders ids in js while clicking on custom created mass action
I have created custom mass action, where I am trying to get all the orders ids which I have selected by using select all, but it gives only visible page ids. So I just wanted to get all selected ids.

If you select all the orders for the mass action, it may take a considerable amount of time to load. As a best practice, I recommended to use pagination to select specific orders and apply the mass action to those selected orders.

@GrazittiDev Right, but if I wanted to achive that, do you have solution for that ?

You can achieve this by using the "Select All" button. When you click on the checkbox in the dropdown section, you'll see the available options. Simply select "Select All," and See if the selected record count is equal to total like image given below :



Yes but if you try to get the all selected ids, then you will get only visible page ids not all, that's the problem

Hey, Check and try once this solution - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290721/admin-grid-select-all-for-mass-action-only-sends-the-visible-ids
